# IOS accessibility VoiceOver: Radiobutton

Tags: ios, radio-button, accessibility, voiceover

With VoiceOver enabled, user hears a message that the user is on the selected radio button 1 of 3 but does not announce any message as to how user can interact with other radio buttons in the group.

Is it a default behavior? or should it also announced any message about how user can interact with radio button?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I used to hear "double tap to activate" all the time on radio buttons and regular buttons but I don't hear it anymore.  My "speak hints" option is turned on in Settings > Accessibility > VoiceOver > Verbosity and I thought that's what controlled whether you heard the interaction hint.  Perhaps an iOS update changed what it announces.

[image: screenshot of verbosity ios setting]

In any event, as long as your HTML is semantically correct (if you're talking about a webpage) or if you're using a native API widget, then you should be ok.  Don't worry about the hint.  iOS will handle that for you.